# passing id parameter to new create action - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Could one kindly advise me how to pass an id through the actions new and create. I have tried many ways to get this right but unfortunately no success.

> what i am aiming to do is, when a jobseeker (user) fills in an
>   application and the application fails the validations, i want a `new
>   form to render with the advert_id passed` through

i have a job advert in which i have passed the advert_id in the apply button

```
advert/show.html.erb
<div class="advert_summary">
  <ul class="content">
    <li><%= @advert.currency %><%= @advert.salarystart %> - <%= @advert.currency %><%= @advert.salaryend %> <%= @advert.category_period.name %></li>
    <li>Job Type: <%= @advert.category_jobtype.name %></li>
    <li>Job Ref: #<%= @advert.reference %></li>
    <li>Posted: <%= @advert.created_at.strftime("%b %d, %Y") %></li>
    <li>Deadline: <%= @advert.appdeadline.strftime("%b %d, %Y") %></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button><%= link_to 'Apply for job', new_form_path(advert_id: @advert.id) %></button>
```

i have the advert_id as a hidden field in my form (the application form for the job)

```
forms/_form.html.erb
<div>
  <h2>Application Form</h2>
  <%= simple_form_for(@form) do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>
    <div class="form-inputs">
      <%= f.input_field :firstname, value: current_user.firstname, label: "firstname", placeholder: "first name" %>
      <%= f.input_field :lastname, value: current_user.lastname, label: "lastname", placeholder: "last name" %>
      <%= f.input_field :tel, value: current_user.tel, label: "number", placeholder: "number" %>
      <%= f.input_field :email, value: current_user.email, label: "email", placeholder: "email" %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :advert_id, value: params[:advert_id] %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.button :submit, 'Submit Application' %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

in my controller forms_controller.rb i have stated the below for the `create action`

```
class FormsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :xml, :json
  before_action :set_form, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def new
    @advert = Advert.find(params[:advert_id])
    @user = current_user
    @form = Form.new
    @search = Advert.search(params[:q])
    @adverts = @search.result(distinct: true)
  end

  def create
    @user = current_user
    @form = Form.new(form_params)
    @advert = @form.advert
    @form.user_id = current_user.id
    @advert = @form.advert
    if @form.save
      redirect_to application_submitted_path
    else
      redirect_to :action => :new, :advert_id => @form.advert_id
      # render :new, :advert_id => @form.advert_id
      # redirect_to :action => :new, :advert_id => @form.advert_id
      # redirect_to user_advert_path(@form.advert.user, @form.advert)
      # respond_with(@form)
    end 
  end
end



models
advert.rb
has_many forms

form.rb
belongs_to advert
belongs_to user (jobseeker)

user.rb (jobseeker)
has_many forms

schemas.rb
  create_table "forms", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "advert_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  create_table "adverts", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "salarystart"
    t.integer  "salaryend"
    t.string   "reference"
  end

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email", 
    t.string   "firstname"
    t.string   "lastname"
  end
```

> when the jobseeker completes the application form
>   (forms/_form.html.erb) and the validation fails the jobseeker(user) is
>   directed to a new form with the advert_id passed through `redirect_to
>   :action => :new, :advert_id => @form.advert_id`
>
> this directs me to a new form, i can see the advert_id has been passed
>   through the url but the form will not submit and error messages are
>   not being displayed.
>
> could one kindly advise me how to successfully pass an id through the
>   actions new and create or where i am going wrong many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    forms/_form.html.erb
    <div>
      <h2>Application Form</h2>
      <%= simple_form_for(@form) do |f| %>
        <%= f.error_notification %>
        <div class="form-inputs">
          <%= f.input_field :firstname, value: current_user.firstname, label: "firstname", placeholder: "first name" %>
          <%= f.input_field :lastname, value: current_user.lastname, label: "lastname", placeholder: "last name" %>
          <%= f.input_field :tel, value: current_user.tel, label: "number", placeholder: "number" %>
          <%= f.input_field :email, value: current_user.email, label: "email", placeholder: "email" %>
          <%= f.hidden_field :advert_id, value: @advert_id %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-actions">
          <%= f.button :submit, 'Submit Application' %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>


    class FormsController < ApplicationController
      respond_to :html, :xml, :json
      before_action :set_form, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

      def new
        @advert = Advert.find(params[:advert_id])
        @user = current_user
        @form = Form.new
        @search = Advert.search(params[:q])
        @advert_id = params[:advert_id]
        @adverts = @search.result(distinct: true)
      end

      def create
        @user = current_user
        @form = Form.new(form_params)
        @advert = @form.advert
        @form.user_id = current_user.id
        @advert_id = params[:form][:advert_id]
        @advert = @form.advert
        respond_to do |format|
          if @form.save
            format.html { redirect_to @form, notice: 'Created.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @form }
          else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @form.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end
    end
```

Comment: @ARTLoe its a pleasure to help someone.